# Why does S.O. on chrome need too much CPU?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-declined, google-chrome

Every now and then I hear my laptop's CPU fan running very high, endlessly.

I poke around (with 'top' for example) to find what process is consuming too much.

Often it turns out to be Chrome, and when I use the Task Manager to find which tab holds the culprit, it frequently turns out to be Stack Overflow.

This began with Ubuntu 12.04 and continues now that I have upgraded to 14.04.

Am I the only one with this issue?

(I tagged this both 'bug' and 'discussion' because I may indeed **be** the only one seeing this)

**Update** : My machine is an 8 core i7 with 16Gb, I often have 25-30 tabs open, in both Firefox and Chrome at the same time, without using even half my RAM or any swap.

**Update** : So are the up votes from people who have noticed the same thing?

**Update** (2014/11/27): I have not seen this problem in quite a while so perhaps a recent upgrade to Chrome or this site(?) has made it go away.

Comment: possibly Chrome tries to avoid _stack overflow_

Comment: hahaha...no no i should not laugh...this is just like another question... shhhhh....... .. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .. . . . . . . . . . . .  **Quick fix** : Get your PC cleaned

Comment: I'd blame Chrome not SO.

Comment: ..because chrome is cr.. err.. 'non-optimal'.

Comment: What kind of machine do you have?  If you don't have a dual-core with 8 gigs of RAM, you don't have enough machine to run Chrome.  How many windows do you have open?  Each one is its own separate process in Chrome.

Comment: Try installing an extension for filtering out extraneous cruft from pages (commonly named after the type of screen-area wasting, bandwidth/CPU hogging cruft invariably served from slow 3rd party sites that it primarily targets).

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Updated to answer you,

Comment: @RobertHarvey Running Chrome with 4 GB of RAM, dual core from '09. Works fine here.

Comment: *"So are the up votes from people who have noticed the same thing?"* Could just be people showing interest.

Comment: I can confirm I see the same issue. Loading **this** meta page even takes about 45 seconds and for the time it's loading, I see 100% CPU usage across all 4 cores. For reference, my machine is fairly beefy. 16G of RAM and i7 quad core, ssd, Arch Linux (up to date), Chrome 38. It's not only stackoverflow I have issues with though. I'm about to try installing beta or unstable to see if that helps. And this is a recent issue. I think last version I used was 35 and I had no problems with it

Comment: if it's a google chrome issue report to them / try updating to 39

Comment: @m0sa - the issue was the uncertainty about the root cause of the issue.  But, see my update . . .

Comment: Try to restart your browser; it happens in browsers a lot. It most likely a bug; this site's design is almost plain links.

Comment: As stated ... I first saw it happening on Ubuntu 12.04, and continued to see it after a complete upgrade to SSD storage and Ubuntu 14.04.